# Reference style where authors are abbreviated with long underscore

Tags: citations, citation-style

What is the name of this reference style? In which other fields have you seen it?

[image]

It replaces author names (in the list of references) with a long underscore when it's the same authors as in the previous item. Also, numbers of the last page are abbreviated if there is too little change. With the latter I am not sure it's part of the reference style, or just a convention.

I found this reference in Economics, namely here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2118200.pdf

Comment: This is... somehow nearly a "cross-site-duplicate" of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29381/is-it-normal-for-bibtex-to-replace-similar-author-names-with (I remember using the `IEEEtran` style recently, thinking *WTF!?* when I noticed this... I had *never* seen it before, and it fortunately seems to be uncommon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen this style in a number of older IEEE publications (in *Computer Science* and related fields). Most commonly, **I have seen this reference style used in *old publications***, and rarely on anything published after 2000.

For another example you can check:

> [L. Vincent, and P. Soille. "Watersheds in digital spaces: an efficient algorithm based on immersion simulations." IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis & Machine Intelligence 6 (1991): 583-598.](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a381/9dda9a5f00dbb8cd3413ca7422e37a0d5794.pdf)

From looking at [this related question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/97402/4249), it seems like it is possible to use this convention in a number of styles (examples in the linked question are provided in both MLA and Chicago citing styles). They further mention that the style is common for *historical books in math*, used by most of the *humanities in the US* as well as *US high-schools* (from where it could reasonably propagate to the higher levels of education).

Answer (score 5):

I don't really agree with the other answer. It's still used in recent publications, and not just in the US. I've recently seen this in the *Annales Mathématiques Blaise Pascal* (random French example) and all AMS publications until very recently (at least 2013, although they changed the style between then and now). "I've never seen this" doesn't really prove anything.